# How do I remove this shower sliding door?

Tags: doors, shower, removal

I'm trying to remove the sliding doors of my shower to clean up the rails and also replace a broken "holder" (sorry I don't know the exact name of that part).

[image: Door holder]

Do you have an idea how to remove a shower door using that hanging system ?

Comment: lift it? also that new holder has a nob what's it for?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the suggestions. Finally, I discovered that there's some hooks on the bottom of the door that you need to release to be able to lift and remove the door.

Answer (score 2):

For most doors, you lift. It will then come out of the bottom track. From there, you just take the door off of the track on top and gently lower it. My tracks are on the outside of my top rail, so the door comes right out the center of the top track opening.